# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax-error

So I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\scanner\mine.php on line 112

On this line:

```
if(preg_match("inurl:", $text) {
```

Its part of a "Clean" function:

```
  function Clean($text) {
        if(preg_match("inurl:", $text) {
            str_replace("inurl:", "", $text);
            return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
        } else {
            return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot a closing ) in that line

Comment: You forgot a closing ) + a semicolon in the end of str_replace + str_replace it self won't do anything in your code, you should add "$text = " be4 it :)

Answer (score 5):

Two problems, One closing ) and a missing semicolon after str_replace, also you should know your str_replace won't do anything in your code so i added $text = ... :)

```
  function Clean($text) {
        if(preg_match("inurl:", $text)) {
            $text = str_replace("inurl:", "", $text);
            return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
        } else {
            return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing `)` on your if statement.

Should be:

`if(preg_match("inurl:", $text)) {`

You're also missing your statement terminator on the string replace. That should be:

```
str_replace("inurl:", "", $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another `)`:

```
if(preg_match("inurl:", $text)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `)` for the `if` condition.

```
  if
    (
      preg_match(
        "inurl:", $text
      ) 
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

The if clause is superfluous anyway. The following function is equivalent to the original version (sans the non-compiling regex pattern).

```
function Clean($text)
{
    $text = str_replace("inurl:", "", $text);
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

If the string you want to replace is not found in the haystack, str_replace won't do anything. So it is safe to run the function unconditionally.

In the original version, you'd also have to surround the regex pattern for preg_match with delimiters (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). (In this case, strpos would do the job, too.)